# Meteor Accounts working with Neo4j

Tags: meteor, neo4j, meteor-accounts

I am trying to get Meteors accounts-password working with neo4j. The "logon" was already cleared in one Topic here, my problem is: How can I get Accounts.createUser to work with Neo4j?

Thanks!

At the moment I am trying with:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Accounts.users = Meteor.neo4j.collection('User');
  Accounts.createUser({username: 'admin', password: 'admin'});
});
```

But this Error is thrown:

```
W20151005-19:43:41.165(2)? (STDERR) { error: 
W20151005-19:43:41.166(2)? (STDERR)    { [Error: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof]
W20151005-19:43:41.166(2)? (STDERR)      message: 'Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof' },
W20151005-19:43:41.166(2)? (STDERR)   uid: 'f0deded1be5deeb03ae2b29de735d81c8ee45fa518600dd16bc5cdf7de581bec',
W20151005-19:43:41.166(2)? (STDERR)   optuid: '6ebc087e0a93a04473772df8d4c2ded5ee59987ee7a870dbc0802930c565d39b',
W20151005-19:43:41.167(2)? (STDERR)   query: 'MATCH (n {_id: {_id}}) WITH count(n) AS count_n WHERE count_n <= 0 CREATE (n {properties})',
W20151005-19:43:41.167(2)? (STDERR)   opts: 
W20151005-19:43:41.167(2)? (STDERR)    { properties: 
W20151005-19:43:41.167(2)? (STDERR)       { createdAt: Mon Oct 05 2015 19:43:41 GMT+0200 (CEST),
W20151005-19:43:41.167(2)? (STDERR)         services: [Object],
W20151005-19:43:41.167(2)? (STDERR)         username: 'admin',
W20151005-19:43:41.168(2)? (STDERR)         _id: '7Dy7t5iJRbj84tFGa' },
W20151005-19:43:41.168(2)? (STDERR)      _id: '7Dy7t5iJRbj84tFGa' },
W20151005-19:43:41.168(2)? (STDERR)   date: Mon Oct 05 2015 19:43:41 GMT+0200 (CEST) }
```

Comment: Which neo4j-meteor binding do you use?

Comment: I dont think this is using ccorcos:neo4j.

Comment: no, i was trying to use https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/neo4jreactivity

Comment: Ah. that package is a little hacky. you need to use mongo for it to work.

Comment: Neo4j doesnt allow nested values, so that could be the source of your error there...